# How to call a function after subscribe is completed

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe

I have this service call where im subscribing to an Observable and assigning the response to a property. My purpose is to call another function thats gonna use this property after the service call is completed. Whats the best way to do this?

```
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
@ViewChild("mapContainer", { static: false }) gmap: ElementRef;
map: google.maps.Map;
markers = [];

 constructor(private userService : UserService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   console.log("Point 1 ##################");
   this.userService.getUserMarkers().subscribe(markers => {
      this.markers = markers;
      console.log("Point 2 ##################");
   });
 }

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   console.log("Point 3 ##################");
   this.mapInitializer();
 }

 mapInitializer(): void {
   console.log("Point 4 ##################");
   // function where to use the markers
 }
```

Now the sequence that happens is,
Point 1 -> Point 3 -> Point 4 -> Point 2

Whats the best way to make it
Point 1 -> Point 2 -> Point 3 -> Point 4

Comment: Any reason you can't call `this.mapInitializer()` after assigning `markers` within the subscribe?

Comment: Only way you could achieve that sequence would be by preloading the user before the component ist initialized. Something like a resolver should do the trick,if the component is routable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it the way you want as [Angular Lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) will be executed as usual. But I guess you need something like:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   console.log("Point 1 ##################");
   this.userService.getUserMarkers().subscribe(markers => {
      this.markers = markers;
      console.log("Point 2 ##################");
      this.mapInitializer();
   });
 }

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   console.log("Point 3 ##################");
 }

 mapInitializer(): void {
   console.log("Point 4 ##################");
   // function where to use the markers
 }
```

So, the new sequence will be: Point 1 -> Point 3 -> Point 2 -> Point 4

Comment: Yes works for the time being. Is there a way i can call `mapInitializer()` every time when the response of subscribe is changed. Ideally when the markers are changed i want to reload the `mapInitializer()`